# Blink build with Xcode failed

Tags: macos, xcode, compile, build

I found [a GPL-ed SIP client for Mac, Blink](http://devel.ag-projects.com/repositories/public/blink-cocoa/). I'd like to build it from source since the binaries are only available as paid download.

Just FYI i'm studying programming at university but have no experience in building complex application from source.

After downloading the content of the repository i opened the Xcode project and tried to build on OS X 10.7, Xcode 4.2.1. Unfortunately the build fail with 1 error and many warnings
Most of the warnings are like this:

```
Attribute Unavailable: Custom Identifiers in Interface Builder versions prior to 3.2
```

The error message is:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error
Command /Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

preceded by the warning

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Warning
directory not found for option '-L/Users/Sergio/Downloads/Blink/devel.ag-projects.com/repositories/public/blink-cocoa/Distribution/Frameworks'
```

I notice that in the list of required files i have this files missing:

```
Dependencies/Frameworks
libgcrypt.11.6.0.dylib
libgcrypt.11.dylib
libgnutls-extra.26.dylib
libgnutls.26.dylib
libgpg-error.0.dylib
libintl.8.dylib
liblzo.1.dylib
libtasn1.3.dylib

Dependencies/Resources
lib

Frameworks/Linked Frameworks
Sparkle.framework

Products
Blink.app
```

It should be possible to download these files somewhere. Unfortunately googling did not help. There's no documentation on the project site.

As Kifosis said, people at the developer website are suggesting to follow [this guide](http://download.ag-projects.com/SipClient/SIPSIMPLE-Manual.pdf)
, unfortunately it's long, unclear (at least for me) and it seems i'll have to install a heck of dependencies, each one of them has a separate download website, separate instructions on how to build them and possibly separate dependencies as well.

All of this seems to me to be very confusing, do i really have to install a bunch of softwares just since they did not include some files in the project directory? I know the GPL v3 may permit this, but it's only encouraging to rely on third party servers (possibly unavailable in the future) and support documentation, let alone when the provided link is too generic, letting people without a really suitable way to get things done.

I'm no expert with installing this required dependencies, i followed the guide i mentioned but when i typed

```
curl -O ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgpg-error/libgpg-error- 1.10.tar.bz2
```

the result was this one:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (78) RETR response: 550
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://ar.libero.it/nxd_an.html">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: @Noughsaid, register your account so that a moderator can merge your old account into your new account.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this did not work is that you have a space between `libgpg-error-` and  `1.10.tar.bz2`:

```
curl -O ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgpg-error/libgpg-error- 1.10.tar.bz2
```

If you run this it works:

```
curl -O ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgpg-error/libgpg-error-1.10.tar.bz2
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it build on OS X Mavericks. I couldn't find an easy way to build those dependencies myself, so I copied them from one of their branded-Blink clients which is available for free.

I have created a gist with instructions: https://gist.github.com/lucaspiller/8194862

Answer (score 0):

looks like they "forgot" including those libraries on purpose! 
I think your best bet would be to contact them directly and ask them where to get all the stuff needed in order to build the app.

I'm no GPL expert, but I believe that it should be an obligation for them to provide you with at least links to the necessary libs, as long as they are licensed under the GPL too, because else they'd be using the GPL just to say "hey, we're cool, we use copyleft" and provide in fact no way to actually build their program, hence defeating the purpose of being an open-source project, even more a GPL-licensed one, which is supposed to be copyleft to the fullest...

Please let me know if you succeed.

Else I'd be glad to buy the app and ask then if I can get an useable source tree; in the event that they refuse, it would obviously be a breach of the GPL's principles.

Good luck!

P.S.:
The commercial IDE Komodo (available as a free trial) might also help building the project, since the latter seems to contain a project file for this IDE

Answer (score 0):

Many of these files seem to be provided by the FSF. You'll have to download the sources and build them before.
Clearly there's another file, lib, inside Dependencies/Resources, that carries no references at all.
You'd be better in contacting the original authors and ask them where to find this "lib"

Answer (score 0):

This is their reply as i emailed them:

From Adrian Georgescu (Ag-projects)

> Those libraries are dependencies from third parties. See SIP SIMPLE
>   Client SDK documentation for how to build them on mac or other OS as
>   those are not Blink dependencies but SIP SIMPLE Client SDK
>   dependencies.

You can find these files at [this site](http://sipsimpleclient.com/) that is also providing a guide.
Still this link is missing from the Download section of the [BLINK website](http://icanblink.com/download.phtml) then they should update this.